# How to run Blazor Web Assembly locally

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to run a Blazor Webassembly app after publishing from the file system, invoking the index.htm in wwwroot? If I do this, the app doesn’t run. The console shows the following errors:

[image]

How can I fix this? Or is it not possible to execute the app in this way?

(For info, this is the .Net 6 Blazor Wasm template without any changes, just created and published the template.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any number of web servers to do that - this is my opinionated answer

https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-serve/#readme-body-tab

### Get started

Install .NET 5 or newer and run this command:

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-serve

### Start a simple server and open the browser by running

dotnet serve -o

..and with HTTPS.

dotnet serve -o -S